# Why do bytes following a variable expansion in a double quoted string override the preceding bytes?

Tags: shell, text-processing, newlines

I am writing a shell script to download the latest version of some software. After I parse the output of `curl` I go through several steps to find the exact version string (at the moment of writing this is `0.65.3`):

(In all code samples below, `>` is my prompt. Output from Bash 3.2 or Zsh is on a line without a `>` prefix.)

```
> url="https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest"
> latest=$(curl --silent --head "$url" | grep Location)
> tag=$(echo "$latest" | cut -d'/' -f8)
> version=$(echo "${tag//v}")
> echo "hugo_${version}_Linux-64bit.tar.gz"
_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
```

The output I expected was `hugo_0.65.3_Linux-64bit.tar.gz`, but in the output of the call to `echo` with the quoted string it seems the bytes following `${version}` have been used to overwrite the bytes at the beginning of the quoted string.

Here I use two different quoted strings to clarify what is happening:

```
> echo "hugo_${version}test"
test_0.65.3
> echo "hugo_${version}lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I get the same **unexpected** result if I do this:

```
> version=$(echo "${tag:1}")
> echo "hugo_${version}_Linux-64bit.tar.gz"
_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
```

But, I get the **expected** result if I do this:

```
> version=0.65.3
hugo_0.65.3_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
```

This last result is what is required, but of course it makes my script static rather than dynamic, and thus not very useful to me. How can I get the desired result without hard-coding the value of `$version` in my script?

Comment: Simpler and more robust if GNU sed: `version=$(curl -sI $url | grep -i ^Location | sed 's:.*/v::; :s\r$::')` HTTP header names are case-insensitive, and I have gotten both Location and location from github. For non-GNU sed can use less-robust `:s.$::` . Or use awk: `version=$(curl... | awk  '/^[Ll]ocation:/{ sub(".*/v",""); sub("\r$",""); print }' )`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @dave_thompson_085. Indeed I feel that using `cut` and hard-coding the field number where I expect the version to be is not very robust.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The line returned by `curl` ends with carriage-return line-feed. (MS-dos line ending). The line-feed is removed by the Unix tools, however this leaves a carriage-return at the end.

Fix this line to use `dos2unix` (and quote your argument to `echo`, avoiding the bugs described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)):

```
version="$(echo "${tag//v}" | dos2unix)"
```

...or, using the shell's built-in syntax to enact *both* changes at once:

```
version=${tag//[$'v\r']/}
```

`dos2unix` does make some other changes (like adding a trailing newline after the last line of text, which UNIX requires but DOS does not), but none of them matter for a single-line string like this.

Comment: I don't have dos2unix (I'm on macOS), but I'll try this in a Docker container soon. In the mean time, can you expand on your answer? I'd like to understand what exactly is happening. Is it that the line that `grep` matched from `curl`'s output ends with `\r\n`?

Comment: Michiel: yes, HTTP headers are _required to end with the ASCII characters CR LF, notated in many (but not all) programming languages and tools `\r \n`.

Comment: I piped `curl`s output to `tr -d '\r'` (for lack of `dos2unix`) before `grep` and now I get the expected result. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 14):

[ctrl-alt-delor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4778/ctrl-alt-delor)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569274/86440) explains why you’re seeing this behaviour; but to address your underlying goal, I recommend using [the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) instead of interpreting the “latest” redirection:

```
version=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest | jq -r '.tag_name | ltrimstr("v")')
```

This asks the API for the information on the latest Hugo release, and extracts the tag name using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), stripping any leading “v”.

Ideally you would even extract the asset names and URLs from the returned JSON.